# Mesh and bones not moving when I use pose mode with rigify rig

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify, pose-mode

I have a model that I have added a rig to with rigify.

I have parented to the rig with automatic weights.

I have then hidden the metarig and am attempting to move the mesh using the control curves. No luck. When I move them the metarig and body do not move with it.

[image: whole screen showing model]

[image: control curve of hand has been moved but mesh does not move with it]

I have checked and I do not have flipped normals anywhere. Also the location of the model is 0,0,0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your model is parented to the metarig and not the generated rig. To fix the issue, clear the parents of your model, delete the vertex groups, then reparent it to the "rig" and not the "metarig".

It should do the trick.

Here is the fixed file: [image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I will try this out. I really appreciate your help amigo. :)